# R Highcharter, hw_grid inside of hw_grid

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am using the highcharter package in R to create subplots, a function that highcharter calls hw_grid. It's fairly straightforward to create a couple plots stacked on top of one another using the following as a code example to get a 3 x 1 grid of charts.

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
MyData <- tibble(xvals=c(1,2,3),yvals=c(4,5,6))
h1 <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(MyData,'line',hcaes(x=xvals,y=yvals))
h2 <-highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(MyData,'line',hcaes(x=xvals,y=yvals))
h3 <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(MyData,'line',hcaes(x=xvals,y=yvals))
subplot <- hw_grid(h1,h2,h3,ncol = 1)
```

What I'd like is for chart number 2 to be a subplot in and of itself, but the hw_grid function doesn't seem to like being nested. In other words, instead of having a 1/1/1 layout of charts vertically, I'd have a 1/2/1 layout of charts, where my second row contains two charts side by side. Here would be an example of how I would expect that to work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
MyData <- tibble(xvals=c(1,2,3),yvals=c(4,5,6))
h1 <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(MyData,'line',hcaes(x=xvals,y=yvals))
h2 <-highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(MyData,'line',hcaes(x=xvals,y=yvals))
h3 <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(MyData,'line',hcaes(x=xvals,y=yvals))
h4 <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(MyData,'line',hcaes(x=xvals,y=yvals))

hSubplot <- hw_grid(h2,h3,ncol=2)
subplot <- hw_grid(h1,hSubplot,h4,ncol = 1)
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance